# Run two loops over Set

Tags: java, list, set

I have `TreeSet` containing customer objects. It contains 10 circle objects. I want to run two loops on the set so that I can compare each element with all the elements down below . Here is the example I can do with `List`, but I am not getting how can I do it with `Set`

```
for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
 // Circle circle = set.get(i);

    for (int j = i+1; i < set.size(); j++) {
        // Circle circle = set.get(j);

    }

}
```

I can do it with  `List<String> list=new ArrayList<>(set)` where i can achieve both sorting(through set) and run two loops on list but  it will be  extra memory .

**What i want to achieve :-**

for each circle in outer loop(sorted  by radius in descending order), i want to calculate the area of each circle in inner loop if that circle is valid(please assume there is a property in circle object which tells whether its valid or not). 
If valid, i need to calculate  the multiplication of circle area in outer and inner loop and find the max result

Comment: Offhand, this sounds like you may be overcomplicating things a bit. What do you want to do in the body of the inner `for`?

Comment: What's the point? Given the way a TreeSet works, you **know** that the first customer will be < to all the subsequent ones. A TreeSet is a SortedSet. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik i wan to do some calculation with all element in inner loop (i.e for each element in outer loop, i wan to to do some processing for all elements in inner loop)

Comment: @JBNizet please see my update for what i want to achieve

Comment: What do you mean by "the multiplication of circles" And what is a "valid circle"? Again, the first circle is the largest one, and the second circle is the second largest one, so, assuming you want to multpiply areas, you can just multiply the two first ones, and you'll have the maximum. No need to loop.

Comment: What does it mean to "multiply" two circles?   When is a circle "valid"?  These requirements make no sense at all.  If you ever figure it out, either do it in a straightforward way or, better yet, use a JDK 8 lambda.

Comment: @JBNizet Oops, I missed that he says that he's got a `TreeSet` going!

Comment: @JBNizet Multiplication of circles meant multiplication of areas of two circles. I have updated the same. Regarding your second statement i.e. `Again, the first circle is the largest one, and the second circle is the second largest one, so, assuming you want to multpiply areas, you can just multiply the two first ones, and you'll have the maximum. `its not  true  because of property isValid in circle object . Updated this too also

Comment: The filter out the invalid circles, and take the two first ones in the set remaining circles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a foreach :

```
for (Customer customer : set ) {    
    for (Customer otherCustomer : set ) {

       // do your processing
    }   
}
```

You cannot retrieve an element from a `Set` with the `get(int index)` method that is specific to the `List` interface.

---

Sorry, I don't make attention to your inner loop condition :

```
 for (int j = i+1; i < set.size(); j++) {
```

You want indeed the inner loop starts after the current element of the external loop.
You could achieve that by declaring your set with the `TreeSet` class and by using the `tailSet()` method :

```
/**
 * @throws ClassCastException {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws NullPointerException if {@code fromElement} is null and
 *         this set uses natural ordering, or its comparator does
 *         not permit null elements
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException {@inheritDoc}
 * @since 1.6
 */
public NavigableSet<E> tailSet(E fromElement, boolean inclusive) {
    return new TreeSet<>(m.tailMap(fromElement, inclusive));
}
```

So you could start the second loop after the current element of the external loop :

```
TreeSet<Customer> set = new TreeSet();
for (Customer customer : set) {
    for (Customer otherCustomer : set.tailSet(customer, false) {
    // do your processing
       System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a close look at how the OP wants to initialize `j`. This isn't the right behavior.

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you. I didn't make attention to it. I updated my answer.

Comment: @davidxxx you'd better use tailSet rather than subSet: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet-E-boolean-

Comment: @davidxxx much better now!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`tailSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet(E,%20boolean)) to get all items starting with the current one:

```
for (Customer outer : treeSet ) {    
    for (Customer inner : treeSet.tailSet(outer, false)) {
        // ...
    }   
}
```

Note the second parameter to which you need to pass `false`. It tells the set to exclude the `outer` element.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement Comparator interface for the same. It will do sort by default based on your requirement.

Please find below code for the same.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        //I am sorting list by name.
        TreeSet<Empl> empls = new TreeSet<Empl>(new EmplNameComp());
        empls.add(new Empl("Jitendra",3000));
        empls.add(new Empl("Kumar",6000));
        empls.add(new Empl("Balla",2000));
        empls.add(new Empl("Puja",2400));
        for(Empl e:empls){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("=====END======");
    }
}

class EmplNameComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
    }
}   

class Empl{

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Empl(String n, int s){
        this.name = n;
        this.salary = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+this.name+" AND Salary: "+this.salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: @scott miles You no need to use two loops for comparing and sorting order you can use compactor

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question at all. And BTW, it's called a comparator, not a compactor.